# Exception encountered: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1095492) when running puppeteer script in Jenkins (Has Debian as machine)

Tags: jenkins, puppeteer, chromium, debian-based

I have developed a nodeJS based project using puppeteer and lighthouse. I am using puppeteer to login to any of the websites where user needs to login. After login, i navigate to any pages like my order, account info, ordered page, etc.

Note- I have this as a free style project on jenkins.

Exact Error in Details-
Exception encountered: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1095492). This can occur if either

1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer).

Tried below 3 scripts to run before calling my script-->

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libgbm-dev
3. npm install -g

npm run MyScriptName

Package.json-->
"devDependencies": {
"chromedriver": "^108.0.0",
"date-and-time": "^2.4.1",
"lighthouse": "^9.6.8",
"log4js": "^6.7.1",
"puppeteer": "^19.7.1"
},

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using the code below:

```
const browserFetcher = puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher();
      let revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download('1095492');

      const browser =await puppeteer.launch({
          executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,
          ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
          headless: true,
          args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disabled-setupid-sandbox"]
        });
```

Comment: headless: true, → headless: false,

it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*index.js*

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  await puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher().download(puppeteer.PUPPETEER_REVISIONS.chromium)
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://example.com/')
  res.send(await page.content())
  await browser.close()
}
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^19.7.5"
  }
}
```

it worked with Google Cloud Functions Node.js 16

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266279679?pli=1

**ES Modules**

*index.mjs*

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
export const helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  await puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher().download(puppeteer.defaultBrowserRevision)
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://example.com/')
  res.send(await page.content())
  await browser.close()
}
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "main": "index.mjs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^19.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now chrome is placed in the user directory `"~/.cache/puppeteer"`. Check the permissions of the directory and that it belongs to the user you are running the application as.

Or set Chromium download folder via `PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR` environment variable or a `puppeteer.config.cjs` config file.